# Counting integers in a sequence with a least prime factor = $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $p > 2$ be a prime.  It is very easy to count the integers in a sequence that are divisible by $p$.

Let $m \ge 0, n > 0$ be integers.  The count of $x$ where $m < x \le (m+n)$ and $p | x$ is at most $1 + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor$.

For example, if $m=6, n=8, p=7$, there are $2$ integers:  $6 < \{ 7, 14\} \le 14$.

Let us assume that in the sequence described by $m,n$, there are $w$ integers where $\text{lpf}(x) \ge p$ where lpf is the [least prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html).

It seems to me that the most $1 + \left\lfloor\frac{n-p}{p}\right\rfloor$ of the $w$ that are divisible by $p$ so that this is an upper bound on the count of integers where $\text{lpf}(x) = p$.

The reason for $-p$ is that we can assume that if there are $2$ or more in sequence, at least one can be ignored since it would be divisible by $2$ and would not be included in $w$.

Is there a flaw in my thinking?  Is there a better upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sieving I find $$\displaystyle w =\sum_{l\in A_{p}} \mu(l)\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{pl} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{m-1}{pl} \right\rfloor\right)$$ where $\ \mu\ $ is the Möbius function and $\ A_{p}\ $ are the ( squarefree ) integers whose largest prime factor is $< p$.

So if $2^p$ is much smaller than $n-m$ :
$$\displaystyle w =\sum_{l\in A_{p}} \mu(l) \frac{n-m+1}{pl}+ \mathcal{O}(2|A_p|)= \frac{n-m+1}{p}\prod_{q \text{ prime}, q < p} \left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)+\mathcal{O}(2^{\pi(p)}) $$

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  Does this analysis suggest that the my analysis is incorrect unless $2^p$ is much smaller than $n-m$?  Could you add details explaining what this says about the upper limit of how many $w$ are divisible by $p$.

Comment: @LarryFreeman Your upper bound simply says that $w \le \lfloor n/p \rfloor$ which is trivial. I wanted to show that using a sieve, you can get more subtle results.

Comment: Apologies.  I'm unclear how it is trivial.  It may be that I am missing something obvious.  Let $R$ be the set of integers between $m$ and $m+n$ where lpf($x$) $\ge p$ so that $|R| = w$.  How can we sure that no more than $\left\lfloor\frac{w}{p}\right\rfloor$ of elements in $R$ are divisible by. $p$.  It seems to me I can find an example where this is not true:  $m=90, n=30, p=7$, $R=\{91, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 119\}$ and $w=8$ but there are more than $\left\lfloor\frac{8}{7}\right\rfloor$.  Please let me know if I am misunderstanding your point.

Comment: @LarryFreeman :  In $[m,m+n] $  there are at most $\lfloor n/p \rfloor+1$ numbers divisible by $p$. This is again trivial.

Comment: @LarryFreeman : And in $[m,n]$ there are exactly $\lfloor n/k \rfloor - \lfloor (m-1)/k \rfloor$ integers divisible by $k$. This is how I got this formula $$ w =\sum_{k \in [m,n], lpf(k) = p} 1 =  \sum_{l\in A_{p}} \mu(l)\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{pl} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{m-1}{pl} \right\rfloor\right)$$ together with the definition of the Möbius function and the inclusion-exclusion principle

Comment: iI apologize if my question was unclear.  I tried to be clear that I am referring to a second-order counting between $m$ and $m+n$.  I agree that the first order is trivial.  I am asking about a second counting after we isolate these factors.  What percentage of these factors that are relatively prime to any prime less than $p$ are divisible by $p$.  I hope my example in my comment makes it clear.  There are 8 that are relatively prime to 30  and 2 that are divisible by 7.  I am interested in the ratio of 2 being divisible out of 8.

Comment: @LarryFreeman Second-order counting ? Try being rigorous, use formulas.

Comment: Apologies if second order counting is the wrong term.  I mean I am looking for a sieve on the results of a sieve.  I am not interested in the number of integers divisible by $p$.  I am interested in the number of integers that have $p$  as a least prime factor.  14 is divisible by 7 but it's least prime factor is 2.

Comment: @LarryFreeman The number of integers in $[m,n]$ with $p$ as least prime factor is $\displaystyle\sum_{k = m, \ lpf(k) = p}^n 1$. This is a formula and it makes clear what I'm talking about. **Use formulas**. Also, did you understand how I obtained $\sum_{l\in A_{p}} \mu(l)\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{pl} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{m-1}{pl} \right\rfloor\right)$ ?

Comment: I am fine with learning more about sieves.  Your equation is clear in meaning but I need to read up on sieves to understand why it is true.  I will accept your answer.  Thanks for explaining your concerns with my question.  My goal here is to learn.  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman It is true because if $p | k$ and $lpf(k) \ne p$ then $pl | k$ with $l$ is a product of primes $< p$. The inclusion-exclusion principle does the rest (count those dividable by $p$, remove those dividable by $2p$ and $3p$, but we counted twice those dividable by $6p$, ...)

Comment: Thanks very much!  That really helps!  That's exactly the answer that I was looking for when I asked this question!  :-)